# HtmlAgilityPack getting page title and H1 tags

Tags: vb.net, tags, browser, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

Hey all i am trying to get the page title and H1 tags from a webpage by doing the following

```
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlSourceCode)

    txtTitle.Text = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title").InnerText()

    txtH1.Text = doc.GetElementsByTagName("H1").InnerText()

    For Each channel In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//meta[@name='description']")
        txtDescription.Text = channel.Attributes("content").Value
    Next
```

The only code above that works is the txtDescription part. Both the title and H1 do not. What type of syntax do i need to use in order to get those 2 tags?

The html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><title>
    The title text is here!
</title><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.zzzz.com/favicon.ico" />
....
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="block-info">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="article">
                <h1>
                    This is the H1 tag with the text!</h1>

<p>As the 2nd held tru
```

Comment: Did you try `doc.DocumentNode.GetElementsByTagName` instead of `doc.GetElementsByTagName`?

Comment: @Oded i get **Public member 'GetElementsByTagName' on type 'HtmlNode' not found.** when doing that.

Comment: What version of HAP are you using? I don't see a `GetElementsByTagName` either on `HtmlDocument` or the `DocumentNode`.

Comment: Are you using the WebBrowser control or the Html Agility Pack? You tags suggest both, but that's probably not true.

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes, both. webbrowser to get the **htmlSourceCode** and then **Html Agility Pack** to parse what i need from that.

Comment: @Oded Please define what **HAP** is?

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title")` and `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//h1")`.

Or `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("title").SingleOrDefault()` and `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h1")`.

Comment: I also get tthe error: **Public member 'DocumumentNode' on type 'HtmlDocument' not found.** using **txtTitle.Text = doc.DocumumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title")** and **Method not found: 'Int32 System.Environment.get_CurrentManagedThreadId()'.** for the **txtTitle.Text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("title").SingleOrDefault()**

Comment: Are you sure you are using the HtmlAgilityPack? These method calls are made on the `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`.

Comment: There is a typo... DocumumentNode should be DocumentNode