# How to get title tag using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm parsing an HTML file using HTML Agility Pack. I want to get

```
<title>Some title <title>
```

As you see, title doesn't have a class. So I couldn't catch it no matter what I have tried. I couldn't find the solution on the web either.  How can I catch this HTML tag which doesn't have a class? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320026/htmlagilitypack-getting-page-title-and-h1-tags

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");
```

or

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title");
```

or

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("title").FirstOrDefault()
```